# Angular undefined variable in

Tags: angular, typescript

I got error from ERROR TypeError: "_co.dashboard is undefined" when I try to call dashboard.all_interviewed in html.

In My dashboard.component.ts

```
dashboard: Dashboard;

    getDashboard() {
      this.dashboardService.getDashboard().subscribe(
        res => {
            this.dashboard = res;
         }
      )
    }
```

In Dasboard Class

```
export class Dashboard {
   all_interviewed: number;
}
```

dashboard.component.html

```
<h2>{{ dashboard.all_interviewed }} </h2>
```

I got this error in console log.

> ERROR TypeError: "_co.dashboard is undefined"
>       View_DashboardComponent_0 DashboardComponent.html:208
>       Angular 32
>       RxJS 5
>       Angular 8 DashboardComponent.html:203:11

Comment: Check spelling in `dashboard.component.html`

Comment: `dasboard` spell mistake. In component it is `dashboard`.

Comment: please change that line

Comment: Hello i don't know why but i can't write answer. this is the shortest snippet: dasboard?.all_interviewed

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code,

```
<h2 *ngIf = "dashboard">{{ dashboard.all_interviewed }} </h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `getDashboard()` on `ngOnInit()` and then try this:

```
<div *ngIf = "dashboard">
   <h2>{{ dashboard.all_interviewed }}</h2>
</div>
```